Should ripples and bulging in new asphalt shingles be corrected?
I just had my roof replaced by a local company. There are a few areas of the work I'm not sure about, so wanted to ask the community whether these are poor quality that need to be repaired by the company, vs "normal" imperfections that can be expected. I'm not a roofing expert, so I can't always tell the difference.

Bumpiness in the shingles

2, 3. Ridge vents seem a bit uneven

Ridge vent seems to tilt up as it goes along the top of the roof?

Ridge vent seems a bit uneven in one section





Thank you!

I believe that the bumpiness is a result of too much heat.  This can be a lack of ventilation in those attic spaces; usually a lack of intake vents.  I think that can also be a result of installing shingles on top of existing ones.
The ridge vent that was installed is the rollout kind from what I can tell.  Part of my home has these and I would like to replace them, though they look like they were installed better than your photos.  If you do replace the ridge vents, opt to spend more on a rigid model.  They look much better and I think they supply more square footage of exhaust area.
I will add that if the bumpiness of the shingles is only present for the dormers, heat is probably the issue for sure. Those attic spaces may be blocked off entirely from the main attic, which is venting.  Two-fold solution: tie those spaces together if possible so that air can flow and get soffit vents to allow cooler air to be taken in at the dormers. I live in a cape cod home, and made major improvements like this.  Before I made these changes, I had ice dams regularly.

Thanks but the pictures were taken 1 day after the replacement of the roof. So, it wouldn't have been heat related.

All of those can be attributed to inadequate settling time. Asphalt shingles need heat and time to flatten and bond to each other. Your weather plays a role, as do sun exposure angle and the nature of the roof--a steep pitch reduces effective gravity and sun angle on some planes and can lengthen the time required.
However, there are other causes for such rippling. A common one is poorly placed underlayment. If it was left with bulges or wrinkles, these are unlikely to flatten in the near term, and may never do so.
The ridge vent type is not visible in your photos. If it's the mesh roll type, varying nail drive depth can result in waviness. Same is true if its the rigid plastic type, but to a lesser degree.
Also factors are roof framing type and condition. Old boards can be uneven or loose. Newer OSB sheathing can be swollen from rain exposure. Framing can sag over time.
The bottom line is that you have a combination of unknown causes and subjective quality assessment here. Wait a few weeks after installation, then talk with your roofer and see if you can get either a good explanation or suitable adjustments to the installation.
